# How to read key from keyboad in red/rebol

Tags: rebol, red, rebol3, rebol2

We can get input from console by `input` or `ask`, which means to press some keys on keyboard and terminate the input by pressing the key "Enter".
I'd like to know if there is a way to get a key input, that is to say, just press a key on keyboard and then something happens, like this:

```
if read-key = #"a" [do something...] ;;if the key "a" on keyboard is pressed, something is done immediately--not by pressing the key "Enter" after pressing "a".
```

If no such any-function! like read-way in red/rebol, how to achieve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to detect esc key with ask function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233670/is-it-possible-to-detect-esc-key-with-ask-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Rebol2 this should work:

```
>> console-port: open/binary [scheme: 'console]
>> pick console-port 1 ; hit space
== 32

>> to char! pick console-port 1  ;hit x
== #"x"
```

Comment: A good solution! Thank you. And is there a Red version?

Comment: @lyl no, Red doesn't have ports ATM. Depending on the task, you may try to hack your way around with View event capturing.

Comment: Thank you alll for these good solution and proposal!

Comment: @9214 Yes, `on-key` event in View is for this. But how to present keys combination, for example, `ctrl a` or `ctrl  shift a` or `alt a`?

Comment: @lyl each event has a set of flags dedicated to that. See [View documentation](https://github.com/red/docs/blob/master/en/view.adoc#112-event-datatype).